# How to investigate the cause of the application crash?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qtquick2, xorg

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64 and the Qt version is 5.8.0.

I have an application based on Qt Quick 2. This application always captures images from a webcam through OpenCV3 VideoCapture, and shows images as fullscreen.

When I rapidly switch the window (by Alt + Tab) after running this application, it will cause Xorg to die but in low possible.

How can I investigate this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Compile the application with the -g flag

From the command prompt, call

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Run your application
The application should core dump.

You can then examine the core using

```
gdb <app> core
```

At the gdb prompt type `bt` to get a callstack.

Comment: What should I do when I can not open tty and ssh?